# How do you specify DynamoDb's conflict resolution policy? (and do I even need to?)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get to grips with DynamoDb, and having read [Vogels 2007 blog post](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html), it refers to syntactic and semantic reconciliation approaches. My app will be fine with 'last write wins' but I want to make sure that I don't have any conflicted items that are sitting in the DB, waiting for the 'client' to resolve them.

I've looked at the AWS API (I was sort of expecting the getItem call to return mulitple version to be resolved by the client) and read the docs and forums but can't find any reference to this. Is this article just referring to something in the dynamo world rather than DynamoDB, and so I don't need to worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamo is not the same as DynamoDB. I know its difficult to believe, but that is the truth. If given a choice between consistency and availability, DynamoDB favors the former. It is just that it increases availability by replicating data in multiple AZs (i.e. availability zones).

To answer your question specifically, `get-item` should always return one version of a record. You needn't worry about picking one version out of many or having conflicting versions in the database.

**Edit**: To clarify, `get-item` always returns *one* version of a record. Whether it is the latest one depends on the [ConsistentRead](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ConsistentRead) flag, which is false by default.

Comment: Thanks. I sort of thought that, but the docs aren't explicit, and finding the differences between dynamo and dynamoDB isn't easy! Good to have the confirmation. Thanks again.

Comment: GetItem may not always return the latest version of an item, depending how you call it. Please see my answer below.

Comment: You downvoted the answer for that one miss? That's what suggested edits are for. And i actually answered the essence of the OP's question

Comment: and if you read carefully, i didn't say get-item always returns the *latest* version of the record. i said it returns *one* version of the record.

Comment: Indeed - I was aware of the ConsistentRead param. I was wondering if a write conflict existed what happened in DynamoDB given what I'd read about Dynamo (from 2007). Specifically I wanted to know if I needed to do any conflict resolution (multiple return values expected from get-item)  or not (single get-item return value). I looked at the API but wanted to confirm I wasn't missing something, which I think has been answered. It would be good knowing how dynamoDb sits in relation to that dynamo paper from 2007 but for what I need now this is enough. Many thanks all.

Comment: So what is the conflict resolution policy DynamoDB follows ? "Last write wins" ? @JohnStephenson

Answer (score 0):

The GetItem API has a [ConsistentRead parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ConsistentRead). If you set it to false, then the read may go to any of the three replicas that host your item. If you set it to true, the read will always go to the master, and you will always get the latest version of the item. Finally, when you set ConsistentRead to false, you are allowed to read twice as much data (8KB) for 1 RCU (Read Capacity Unit) so reads are cheaper when they are eventually consistent.