# DynamoDB conflict resolution strategy

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What is the conflict resolution strategy for DynamoDB ? The white paper on Dynamo talks about returning multiple versions by GetItem to be resolved by the client.

This SO  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933959/how-do-you-specify-dynamodbs-conflict-resolution-policy-and-do-i-even-need-to)  says that Dynamo and DynamoDB are different and GetItem returns only one value. In that case, what is the conflict resolution strategy that DynamoDB employs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, your question is not very clear: "What is the conflict resolution strategy for DynamoDB" - what conflicts? Are you referring to potentially inconsistent reads?

DynamoDB, for GetItem queries, allows both eventual consistent and strongly consistent reads, configurable with a parameter on the request (as described in the docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html). For strongly consistent reads the value returned is the most recent value at the time the query was executed. For eventual consistent reads it is possible to read a slightly out of date version of an item but there is no "conflict resolution" per se.

You may be thinking about conditional updates which allow for requests to fail if an expected condition is not met at the time the query is executed.

Comment: For strongly consistent reads the value returned is the most recent value at the time the query was executed :  This was what I wanted. So "last write wins" is the conflict resolution strategy that DynamoDB employs.

Comment: Great! Happy to help

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can you guide me to any documentation that talks about this ? I have looked hard but could not find any

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html

Comment: And what if there are 2 concurrent writes? How can a define the strategy for how to properly resolve the conflict. In the paper they describe a conflict resolution mechanism for the Cart, but I can't see anywhere in the public APIs on how to define my own.

Comment: Hi @Bob9630 - DynamoDB offers two options for writes: 1) either unconstrained, in which case both writes will be applied non-deterministically (meaning the writes get applied in whatever order they happen to be processed) or 2) constrained with a conditional expression such that you can dictate that it is illegal for two writes to be applied - so only one will succeed and the other will fail with an exception (then you have to implement your own retry logic);  this is really a separate question that a comment cannot do justice - I encourage you to ask a new question if you’re still unclear

Comment: @MikeDinescu My questions is actually the OP's question. In the event of a partition (ie not all hosts in the distributed system can communicate) and two writes are made to hosts which can't communicate, once communication is restored, how is the "winning" write reconciled. The original paper describes the resolution policy. The implementation speaks nothing of it. This is a standard distributed system problem. RDBMS system give a clear answer, the write will fail in the event of partition. Is the DynamoDB implementation a relaxation of the "all writes succeed" property of the dynamo paper?

Comment: @Bob9630 you're asking a different question than the OP; actually, you're asking 2 different questions, in a comment! your 1st question is about how Dynamo handles network partitions with respect to writes and your 2nd question is what happens when there are two distinct writes happening on partitioned hosts; my previous comment still applies with one more clarification - DynamoDB writes are guaranteed to be strongly consistent; please ask a new question and you'll get a proper answer (potentially multiple answers). these comments are difficult to author and don't serve the community well

Comment: I see. It seems the dynamo paper and the actual DynamoDB implementation are in conflict. This was what the OP was asking about. Consistent writes aren't possible in the face of partitions assuming all writes are successful (availability) by the CAP theorem. The paper favored Availability over Consistency. It seems the implementation favors Consistency over Availability. Partitions are just an unfortunate way of life in the cloud and thus can't be avoided :-) Conflict resolution is only necessary if conflicts are allowed.

https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf

Comment: I should also clarify that in this case, the notation of conflicting writes pertains to writing to the same key when the write request is sent to partitioned hosts. I assume based on your above answer, the solution is the write fails if a quorum of the hosts responsible for the key cannot be found. Thank you, this clarifies my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

See this
"Conflicts can arise if applications update the same item in different regions at about the same time. To ensure eventual consistency, DynamoDB global tables use a “last writer wins” reconciliation between concurrent updates, where DynamoDB makes a best effort to determine the last writer. With this conflict resolution mechanism, all of the replicas will agree on the latest update, and converge toward a state in which they all have identical data."

So the latest write wins based on some for of consensus between the replicas.

Comment: DynamoDB's UpdateItem doesn't require a write to completely overwrite an item, and he can just modify one or several attributes. So the concept "last writer wins" is no really useful: If two writers modify *different* attributes concurrently, both writers can "win", there is no real conflict - but will they? Or because of implementation details, the second write may undo the previous update?

Comment: You're quoting the documentation for DynamoDB Global Tables, but as far as I can tell the question is asking about "standard" single-region DynamoDB.  You may wish to revise your answer.