# Does DynamoDB expose an API to query or detect when there is conflict in merging item data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB is an AP system based on the original [dynamo paper](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html).

- Is there any API to detect when a merge conflict has happened or resolved?
- Is there any API to provide a strategy to resolve a conflict if it happens.

Comment: "DynamoDB is an AP system based on the original dynamo paper." - as Jaso Sorensen said in [his re:invent talk about DynamoDB under the hood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvBR71D0nAQ), it has a lot of differences compared to the original Dynamo paper. Please be more precise with your question. What merge conflicts are you talking about? If you make people read an academic paper before they can even begin to guess what you want to know, you might not get a lot of responses.

Comment: The answer on this question, and in particular the comments, may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329936/dynamodb-conflict-resolution-strategy

Comment: @Maurice I was trying to better understand dynamodb from the docs to compile notes - https://rahulrevo.substack.com/p/redefining-amazon-dynamodb. The original dynamo paper was the only reference I knew earlier. Thanks for your "under the hood" talk since that did help my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is based on a wrong premise. Although DynamoDB shares the name, and some goals and implementation details, with the original "Dynamo" paper, it is not very close, and the data model in particular is completely different.

Whereas in the Dynamo paper multiple clients could store multiple different values for an item concurrently - and later readers need to resolve the conflict - DynamoDB does things very differently:

1. If two clients replace an item, DynamoDB offers a "last write wins" - one of these writes will win, you don't know or care which.
2. If two clients modify different attributes in the same item concurrently, both changes will be merged. I never found this explicitly promised, but it appears to work this way.
3. You also have a powerful **conditional update** feature, which can do a modification to a single item based on some condition on the old value of this item. These conditional updates are guaranteed to be isolated, so they can be used to ensure safe concurrent modification. For example, a conditional update can be used to implement so-called **optimistic locking**: An item has a version attribute among other attributes, a client reads the old item, decides what to change it to, and then does the write - with the *condition* that the version still hasn't changed. If the condition fails (because some other client raced us), the write fails and the client tries the whole process again (read again, apply a change, and write back).
4. DynamoDB also has a new feature of full (multi-item) transactions. This feature did not exist in Dynamo at all.